# How do I request a token from a ASP.Net Core Web API in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, rest, http, urlencode

I created an ASP.NET CORE Web API that uses Microsoft OAuth to control access to the API which I created using the available `ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)` template. When I use the `PostMan` application to make an http request to `https://localhost:44365/token` with body and use `x-www-form-urlencoded`:

`{"grant_type": "password", "username": "username", "password": "password"}`
I get the access token but when I try to send a post request using HTTPClient in Angular

```
const body = new HttpParams()
        .set('grant_type', "password")
        .set('username', user["username"] + "@gmail.com")
        .set('password', user["password"]);

      let headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

      this.http.post("https://localhost:44365/token", body.toString(), { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.token = data["access_token"];
          resolve(null)
        }, err => {
          reject(err);
        });
```

I get the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44365/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

which I then tried to fix using an extension `Moesif Origin & Cors Changer` and I still get an error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44365/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I am pretty sure my Typescript is wrong. So how do I fix the CORS problem and my POST request?

Comment: Do you have an OPTIONS route in your web api that is not access controlled? Angular uses the OPTIONS method for preflight checks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow CORS in your API. 
In your Startup.cs file you can either add

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader());
```

(4200 is the port of the angular app. If it's different in your case then change it)

Of

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyCredentials());
```

Comment: My API uses a ConfigureAuth method that creates app as an instance of IAppBuilder and not IApplicationBuilder so `app` doesn't have a `UserCors()`  method